# How to customize bold title text in VF Page Message created from Apex

Tags: visualforce

Ist there any way to modify the bold title of `ApexPages.Message` when created via code?
[image]

I know that you can alter this when you construct the message via `apex:pageMessage`

Comment: Find out how you can identify that message (id of html element or does it use a certain CSS class) and then override the styling in your local CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the third (less common) form of constructing a message:

```
new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity, summary, detail);
```

Also, you'll need to make sure you're showing summary and detail information on the `apex:pageMessages` element (`showDetail` should be `true`).

Answer (score 3):

If you are showing custom error message from controller on page using ApexPages.Message then you can use html bold tag i.e.  in the message like this

```
new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity,'<b>Error: Invalid Input.</b>');
```

And on the page where you use  tag you can use attribute "escape" like this

```
<apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>
```

I hope this answers your question.